# Add build information in Jenkins using REST

Tags: python, post, jenkins

Does anyone know how to add build information to an existing Jenkins build?

What I'm trying to do is replace the #1 build number with the actual full version number that the build represents. I can do this manually by going to http://MyJenkinsServer/job/[jobname]/[buildnumber]/configure

I have tried to reverse engineer the headers using chrome by seeing what it sends to the server and I found the following:

```
Request URL:http://<server>/job/test_job/1/configSubmit
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:192
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:hudson_auto_refresh=false; JSESSIONID=qbn3q22phkbc12f1ikk0ssijb; screenResolution=1920x1200
Referer:http://<server>/job/test_job/1/configure
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.79 Safari/537.4

Form Data view URL encoded
displayName:#1
description:test4
core:apply:true
json:{"displayName": "#1", "description": "test4", "": "test4", "core:apply": "true"}**

Response Headers view source
Content-Length:155
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Server:Jetty(8.y.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

This at least gives me the form parameters that I need to POST. So from this I came up with the following python3 code:

```
import requests
params={"displayName":"Hello World",
    "description":"This is my description",
    "":"This is my description",
    "core:apply":"true"}

a = requests.post("http://myjenkinsserver/job/test_jira_job_update/1/configSubmit", data=params, auth=( username, pwd), headers={"content-type":"text/html;charset=UTF-8"} )
if a.raw.status != 200:
    print("***ERROR***")
    print(a.raw.status)
    print(a.raw.reason)
```

but sadly this failed with the following error:

```
***ERROR***
400
Nothing is submitted
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Is my approach to this problem completely wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit confusing to reverse engineer this. You just need to submit the *json* parameter in your POST:

```
p = {'json': '{"displayName":"New Name", "description":"New Description"}'}
requests.post('http://jenkins:8080/job/jobname/5/configSubmit', data=p, auth=(user, token))
```

In my tests, the above works to set the build name and description with Jenkins 1.517.

(Also, I don't think you should set the content-type header, since you should be submitting form-encoded data.)

Comment: Thank you Dave, after removing all the other code "noise" and headers all is working.

Answer (score 3):

Came here (from google) and i had this issue as well. in addition to Dave's answer, this may help those who try to trigger a build with parameters and get this error...

```
import json
import requests

job_name = "my-jenkins-job"
job_parameters = [
    {
        "name": "ip_address",
        "value": "192.168..."
    },
    {
        "name": "url",
        "value": "http://..."
    },
    {
        "name": "architecture",
        "value": "x86"
    }
]

data = {"json": json.dumps({"parameter": build_parameters})}
r = requests.post('http://<jenkins server>/job/{job_name}/build/api/json'.format(job_name=job_name), data=data)
r.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try list of tuple instead of dictionary, and urlencode it.

```
params=[("displayName","Hello World"),
    ("description","This is my description")]
dataParam = urllib.urlencode(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters list has changed.  Also be sure you have the same number of keys defined in the Jenkins UI. If not 400 or 500!

```
param = {"parameter": [{"name": "CustomerName", "value": "AcmeCorp"}]}
data = {"json": json.dumps(param)}
headers["content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.
.
.
r = requests.post(jobURL, headers = headers, data=data)
```