# How to POST with Curl to configSubmit Jenkins page

Tags: curl, jenkins, jetty, http-post, jenkins-api

I can do it with Python but not with Curl...

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" --data-urlencode   \
   '{ "description": "This is a test job.", "displayName": "#30: Success" }' \
   -n http://localhost/job/playground/30/configSubmit


<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /job/playground/30/configSubmit. Reason:
<pre>    Nothing is submitted</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>
```

Comment: I get this same problem with 
`curl -u <username>:<token>  -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data-urlencode "description=hello world" https://jenkins.local/job/<job_name>/<build_id>/configSubmit`, 
`curl -u <username>:<token>  -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST --data'{"description": "hello world"}' https://jenkins.local/job/<job_name>/<build_id>/configSubmit`
and a whole bunch of other renditions on the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with this for several hours.  Ultimately, [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21710010/1508243) got me unstuck.

It seems like Jenkins is expecting form data that has a field called `json`.  The curl command that ultimately worked for me was

```
curl -X POST -F 'json={"displayName":"name","description":"a short description"}' \
  http://localhost/job/playground/30/configSubmit
```

Answer (score 2):

@Pete answer is correct however it suffices running:

`curl -F 'json={"displayName":"name","description":"a short description"}' \ http://localhost/job/playground/30/configSubmit`

A bit more explanation:

- The `-F` option in curl is used to post a form so `-X POST` not necessary.
- `json=` is needed and equivalent to setting `Content-Type: application/json`.
- `--data-urlencode` (as used in the question) when used it overrides `-F` - so it can't be used here.

@ebeezer issue comes from attempting to set only "description" while it is necessary to set both "description" and "displayName" for the request to succeed.